# Angular 2 http.delete -Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

Tags: asp.net, angular

I'm trying to call the http.delete request to my server.

```js
deleteStudent(id){
    let body = JSON.stringify({"Id":id});
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    this.http.delete('http://localhost:10090/app/Test/'+id,{headers:headers}).subscribe((res) => {
});
```

here is my Server code in C# web API

```js
 [HttpDelete]
        [Route("app/Test/{id}")]
        public void deleteByid(int id) {

        }
```

Error Code

```js
OPTIONS http://localhost:10090/app/Test/2 405 (Method Not Allowed)

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:10090/app/Test/2. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Headers, …}
```

Comment: It's written in the error : the `delete` method isn't allowed. It's not Angular related, but back-end related.

Comment: server code is expecting only id , not sure why are you setting headers and stringify body. you dont need them. try removing the headers and out a breakpoint on server and check if it hits the server